# Connect DHT11 and HC-SR04 to one Raspberry Pi with one breadboard

Tags: pi-3, sensor

I have two sensors, a temp/humid sensor DHT11 and an ultrasonic distance sensor HC-SR04. My ultrasonic sensor is already connected with my raspberry pi through a breadboard. Now I want to connect the DHT11 to the same raspberry pi through the same breadboard, because I don't want to waste money on another raspberry pi just for the second sensor. Can I technically do that ? I am using pin 2,6,16,18 for the ultrasonic sensor, the rests are free. Just want to be sure whether it's doable or not before I try it.

Comment: Yes. It's very doable.

Comment: In theory, you can connect hundreds of devices to a Pi. In practice... see for yourself.